# Combined events (Probability)

Tags: probability

A card us picked from a pack containing 52 playing cards. It's then replaced and a second card is picked. Find thee probability that

a)Both cards are the seven of diamonds,

b)The first card is a heart and the second a spade,

c)One card is from a black suit and the other from a red suit,

d)at least one card is Queen.

My attempt,

a)$\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{1}{52}=\frac{1}{2704}$

b)$\frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{16}$

How to solve question c and d?

Comment: d - try to think of the probability of both cards *not*  Q.

c - 2 options here: 1)first black second red . 2) first red, seconds black.

Comment: I know the answer for c is $\frac{1}{2}$. But I don't know how to compute out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

c) there are exactly $2$ 'disjoint' possibilities: "the first is black and the second is red" and "the first is red and the second is black".

d) $1$ minus the probability that both cards are no queens.

Comment: For d). I got the answer which is $\frac{25}{169}$

For c) Can you explain more? Thanks a lot

Comment: simply add the 2 probabilities. can you see why it is right ?

Comment: Your answer on d) is correct. Can you find the (first mentioned) probability that the first card is red and the second is black? If two events $A, B$ are disjoint then $P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)$

Comment: @drhab. Is the $P(A)=\frac{26}{52}$?

Comment: The probability that the first card is red is $\frac12$ and the probability that the second card is black is $\frac12$. These events are independent, so the first mentioned probability is $\frac12\times\frac12=\frac14$. Likewise for the second mentioned probability you find $\frac14$. Finally $\frac14+\frac14=\frac12$.